# name of type="action" in openerp button

Tags: odoo

I've a problem when I want to make button in `type="action"`, it's really different with `type="object"`. I just want to make button that can connect one module to another.  It already exists in openerp for a few buttons of `type="action"`.  I just want to understand what is the function of `"name"` of this button?

I have an example, I found this xml script in backend sale folder:

```
<button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d"
 string="Create Invoice"
 type="action"
 states="manual"
 class="oe_highlight"
 groups="base.group_user"/>
```

when I installed sale module, then I see the xml script in frontend `sale.order.form`, it's already change into:

```
<button name="278"
 string="Create Invoice"
 type="action"
 states="manual"
 class="oe_highlight"
 groups="base.group_user"/>
```

What's happening with the `"name"`? Can anyone give me a simple button of `type="action"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three kinds of types for button:  **object**, **action** & **workflow**. **workflow** is the default.

Now let's understand the meaning of these three types:

1. `object` is used if you want to call a **method** which is written in `.py` file.
2. `action` is used if you want to call any **action** which is written in `.xml` file. Let say if you want to open a wizard from button click then you can use `type="action"`.
3. `workflow` (the default) is used if you want to call **workflow**.

---

```
<button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d"
 string="Create Invoice"
 type="action">
```

when **Create Invoice** button is clicked, you will see a wizard.

```
<button name="278" string="Create Invoice" type="action">
```

Here `278` is an **ID** in postgresql database of `action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv` action.

Comment: where can i find "278"? 
i found this id in..
<record id="action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Invoice Order</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>

Comment: Yes, it's in sale module. Are you facing any problem?

Comment: it fixed. thank's. it is automatically put the parameter to the intended view.