# How does this OpenERP button work

Tags: odoo

I have come across some code in an OpenERP xml view, and I cannot understand how it works.

```
<button name="%(account.action_account_invoice_refund)d" type='action' string='Refund' states='open,paid' icon="gtk-execute"/>
```

- What does the % mean
- What is the d at the end?
- why is there account (dot) action_account_invoice_refund

There is no method in the system called **account_invoice_refund**, but there is a class:

```
class account_invoice_refund(osv.osv_memory):
```

A traditional button, where it calls a method, looks like this:

```
<button name="invoice_cancel" states="proforma2,open" string="Cancel" icon="gtk-cancel"/>
```

Comment: i think this question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682253/name-of-type-action-in-openerp-button

Comment: The linked question says that unless it is workflow (default) then the type must be object or action. The invoice_cancel button above calls python code but does not have type=object

Comment: if button call from workflow then it is action else object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button type  is of type action so it will trigger an action,which is called by module.xml_id.

So it will search action  xml view named as  action_account_invoice_refund in account module

The action will be found in wizard folder of account module

Use grep function to find the xml

For example :

use grep -rn "action_account_invoice_refund" . in account module folder

It will show